# How do I complete a set of three vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$ to a basis of that space?

Tags: vector-spaces

Given vectors $$w_1 (0,-1,2,1),\quad w_2 (1,0,2,1),\quad w_4 (2,1,1,0),$$
how do I find another vector $v$ such that $\{w_1, w_2, w_4, v\}$ is linearly independent?

My approach is to write them all in matrix form and then try and row-reduce them, but if one row is just $a,b,c,d$ and others with numbers, how will I be able to show it is a basis? Or am I missing a point here?

Can I just take the 3 given vectors and row-reduce them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A set of $n$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is linearly independent iff the $n \times n$ matrix produced by adjoining them is nonsingular, which means we need to find a vector $(a, b, c, d)^T$ such that
$$\det\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 2 & a \\ -1 & 0 & 1 & b \\ 2 & 2 & 1 & c \\ 1 & 1 & 0 & d \end{pmatrix} \neq 0.$$

You could expand this, which would take some work, or you can observe that, e.g., the vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ produced by projecting the $w_i$ onto the first three components are themselves linearly independent, so if we set $a = b = c = 0$, we have
$$\det\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 2 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 & d \end{pmatrix} \neq 0 = -(d) \det \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 2 \\ -1 & 0 & 1 \\ 2 & 2 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \neq 0,$$ provided $d \neq 0$. So, any vector $(0, 0, 0, d)^T$, $d \neq 0$, does the trick.

Comment: so is there a v Vector from R^4 such that w1,w2,w3,v are Basis of R^4?

Comment: if yes what is it? thnks

Comment: The last sentence of the answer gives some possible answers.

Answer (score 2):

If you place the three given vectors as rows of a matrix and do row-reduction, the set of vectors spanned by the rows *after* reduction will be the same as the set spanned *before* reduction (assuming you do it right). But AFTER reduction, it should be easier to find a vector not in the span of your rows. For instance, if you ended up with 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 3 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix},
$$
then the vector $[0, 0, 1, 0]$ would not be in the row span.

Comment: I appologise, i didn't understand your approach.